# If today is greater than or equal to end date return to Yes. (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, formula, calculated-columns

How do I write this formula successfully in a calculated field in a SharePoint list?

I've tried many ways I can keep receiving a technical error message.

I have a today columns and an end date column.

Status column will either equal yes or no.

I hope some can assist with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to list settings and create 3 columns as follows:

1) **TodaysDate** of type Datetime with date only option. Choose the "Today's Date" default value.

2) **EndDate** of type Datetime with date only option.

3) **Status** of type Calculated Field. Enter the following formula in the Formula Box:
=TodaysDate>EndDate

Also, Choose The data type returned from this formula is: Yes\No

Now, go to the list enter some data. Following is the example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not use [Today] in calculated columns. The field will be updated when the item is updated. If the item is never updated the field contains the date when the field has been created!

**To create a column which displays if a date is lower/greater as the current day is not possible!**

Also the HTML trick using javascript does not work anymore, the functionality has been removed!